# select data from multiple table using php union

Tags: php, mysql

anyone can help me how to select from multiple MySQL table and sort by the gameplayed limit 15 using php?

```
   <?php
   //$query = "SELECT id, gamename, gameplayed FROM action, adventure, augur, beauty, chess, joke, mmorpg, multiplayer, platform, puzzle, racing, shooting, sport, stratergy WHERE id = :id";
   $query = '
     SELECT id, gamename, gameplayed FROM((
     SELECT id, gamename, gameplayed 
     FROM action 
 ORDER BY gameplayed
 DESC LIMIT 15 
 ) UNION (
     SELECT id, gamename, gameplayed
     FROM adventure
     ORDER BY gameplayed
     DESC LIMIT 15
     ))as t ORDER BY gameplayed';

     $query_params = array(':id' => '1'); 
     //$query = "SELECT id, gamename FROM action, adventure, augur, beauty, chess, joke, mmorpg, multiplayer, platform, puzzle, racing, shooting, sport, stratergy ORDER BY gameplayed DESC LIMIT 15"; 
     try 
      { 
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params); 
      } 
     catch(PDOException $ex) 
      { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
      } 

      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
        foreach($rows as $row):
        echo $rows['t'];
        endforeach;
        unset($row); 
        ?>
```

i search google found the solution is using union , but i'm keep getting error "undefine index t"

Comment: What `echo $rows['t'];` should do ?

Comment: `t` is your table alias, so it cannot be used in `$rows[]`. Try using `$rows['id']`, `$rows['gamename']`, or `$rows['gameplayed']` in your `foreach($rows as $row):`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SQL query to this

```
SELECT id, gamename, gameplayed 
FROM action 
LIMIT 15 
UNION
SELECT id, gamename, gameplayed
FROM adventure
ORDER BY gameplayed DESC 
LIMIT 15
ORDER BY gameplayed
```

Comment: if all the table contain around 30 thousand rows , will it take long time to do the query?

Comment: No, since you have the limits applied. It should run fast.

Answer (score 0):

It don't see a field named "t" in your select query? Try to `var_dump()` `$rows`, then you may see whats going wrong.

What you are doing is trying to select a table alias. You cannot select them, only select fields.

Your result should now look at the beginning of the subarrays of your array `$rows` like the elements of the first table and the second, mixed, following the order in the `gameplayed` column.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to make all the results from the UNION select as an alias `'t'` ? It won't work, you have to use them one by one i.e.:

```
...UNION (
 SELECT t.id as 'tid', t.gamename as 'tgamename', t.gameplayed as 'tgameplayed'
 FROM adventure AS t
 ...


$row['tid']; $row['tgamename']; $row['tgameplayed']
```

Comment: Never tested, but if it unions the results in the first column names mentioned, won't you be able to return the data only from the unioned select if its own columns have aliases? And the overall result without alliases?

Comment: You'll have a lot of empty rows with this query.

Comment: hmm... may i know what this meaning ?"t".id as tid , what is the "t" stay for?